# Javascript array assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ammap

I'm trying to draw lines using ammap and I'm stuck generating an array of coordinates for start and end points. I have to json arrays with that have case_study as the key as shown below

```
var data = {
  "countries_involved": [
    {"c_id": 6, "country": "India", "longitude": "21", "latitude": "78.0000", "involvement": 3, "case_study": 4},
    {"c_id": 7, "country": "Canada", "longitude": "62", "latitude": "105.3809", "involvement": 3, "case_study": 4}, 
    {"c_id": 8, "country": "Comoros", "longitude": "12", "latitude": "44.2333", "involvement": 1, "case_study": 5},
    {"c_id": 9, "country": "Madagascar", "longitude": "20", "latitude": "47.0000", "involvement": 1, "case_study": 5},
    {"c_id": 10, "country": "Mauritius", "longitude": "20", "latitude": "57.5000", "involvement": 1, "case_study": 5}
  ],
  "country_details": [
    {"name": "Kenya", "longitude": "-1", "latitude": "36.8000", "case_study": 4},
    {"name": "Kenya", "longitude": "-1", "latitude": "36.8000", "case_study": 5}
  ]
};
```

I'm using jquery filter to return data in the following format

```
{longitudes: [country_details.longitude,countries_involved.longitude], latitudes: [country_details.latitude,countries_involved.latitude],}
```

here's my function within a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.country_details.length; i++)
{
  var obj = {
    id: data.country_details[i]['name'].replace(/\s+/g, ''),
    color: "#000000",
    svgPath: targetSVG,
    title: data.country_details[i]['country'],
    latitude: data.country_details[i]['longitude'],
    longitude: data.country_details[i]['latitude'],
    scale: 1.5,
    zoomLevel: 2.74,
    lines: data.countries_involved.filter(function(involved) {
      return involved.case_study === data.country_details[i].case_study
    }).map(function(item) {
      return {latitudes: [data.country_details[i].latitude, item.latitude], longitudes: [data.country_details[i].longitude, item.longitude]}
    })
  };
}
```

However, I only get an array with only for start points and not endpoints meaning `item.latitude` and `item.longitude` are not evaluating. Can anyone help out please?

Comment: I see values in both "latitudes" and "longitudes".  What's the problem?  http://jsfiddle.net/qSf3d/2/

Comment: not working on my computer, this is what i get on my console.log

[Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}, Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}, Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}, Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}, Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}, Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}, Object { latitudes=[2], longitudes=[2]}]

Comment: the result should be something like this {longitudes: [start_longitude,end_longitude], latitudes: [start_latitude,end_latitude],}

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking.  I suggest adding the exact output you're expecting (also tell us what value `i` has).

Comment: i have updated the code to show surrounding for loop

Answer (score 2):

Within this piece of the code:

```
data.countries_involved.filter(function(involved){
    return involved.case_study === data.country_details[i].case_study
}).map(function(item){
    return {
        latitudes: [data.country_details[i].latitude, item.latitude], 
        longitudes: [data.country_details[i].longitude, item.longitude]
    };
});
```

the variable 'i' is not defined.

I believe in the case of built-in javascript array 'map' and 'filter' functions the index within the collection you are iterating is passed as the *second* parameter.  So declare 'i' as the second argument in these two lines:

```
data.countries_involved.filter(function(involved, i){
// and:
}).map(function(item, i){
```

Edit:
Array.prototype.map and Array.prototype.filter are not available in all browsers.  To use jQuery map and filter instead do this:

```
$($.grep(data.countries_involved, function(involved){
    return involved.case_study === data.country_details[i].case_study
})).map(function(idx, item){
    return {
        latitudes: [data.country_details[i].latitude, item.latitude], 
        longitudes: [data.country_details[i].longitude, item.longitude]
    };
}).get()
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the code lies within a for loop to get countries then attach the respective involved countries in the above function

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't clear... can you post the surrounding code please?

Comment: There still isn't enough context.  What happens to the output of the call to .map()?  as written it isn't assigned anywhere, which means it gets ignored and thrown away...

Comment: Sorry for making too many assumptions. I've got the whole loop up now

Comment: I get exactly the result I would expect.  I'm running in Chrome on the console.  You stated you are using jQuery filter, but in your code you appear to be using Array.prototype.map and Array.prototype.filter.  Incidentally, these are not supported in some older browsers... what environment are you testing in?

Comment: You're right! can you be kind enough to assist it rewriting the for all browsers, I'm at a loss from here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39448/discussion-between-mike-edwards-and-edgar-ochieng)